# Set data from localStorage when user is connected

Tags: javascript, save

I have been working on a save file for my game. The save file IS working, and console.log displays proper values:

```
function saveGame(){
    localStorage.setItem('game', JSON.stringify(game));
}
function loadGame(){
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('game');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
}
```

Image of the logs: https://s28.postimg.org/bslusmagt/Untitled.png
[image]

I'm still new to all this as I have started learning JS couple of months ago. Right now my guess is that when the page is loaded, I'm supposed to set all these values. Trying the next thing i get "null" in console.log

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game.plutonium')));
```

I thought values could be set something like:

```
game.plutonium = localStorage.getItem('game.plutonium');
```

But it doesn't work. Whats the trick here?

Here is my full JS code, just in case: http://pastebin.com/yM2wz410

Values are defined from line 1, and save / load file is on the line 350-356.
Why doesn't my method work?

```
function saveGame(){
     var savefile = JSON.stringify(game);
     localStorage.setItem("game", savefile);
}

function loadGame(){
     var savefile = localStorage.getItem("game");

     if (savefile === null) {
         return;
      }

     game = JSON.parse(savefile);
 }
```

Method above seems to have completely solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` changes the object you give it into a string (which can be stored very easily). But: you can't navigate that string anymore via `string.key`

To translate that json string back into a object (that can be navigated again), you need to use `JSON.parse()`.

Your problem above is, that you store the whole object (as json) into the storage with key `game` and then try to get the item `game.plutonium` from the storage. Note that you didn't save anything as `game.plutonium`.

You need to first fetch the whole json string via `localStorage.getItem('game')`, then parse the string back to an object and only then you can navigate over it again like `game.plutonium`.

```
var game = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game'))
var plutonium = game.plutonium;
```

Comment: I have managed to get it to work with

function saveGame(){
 var savefile = JSON.stringify(game);
 localStorage.setItem("game", savefile);
}

function loadGame(){
 var savefile = localStorage.getItem("game");
 game = JSON.parse(savefile);
}

But the problem now occurs on gamestart. If i loadGame and localStorage is empty game doesn't work. if I saveGame first then i will always override saved data... I'm trying to find a work around using a boolean

Comment: you will need to check if the item you get from localStorage actually already existed, and only then load it into your game object. If it didn't exist (`getItem()` returns null), populate your game object with some defaults (no savegame existed; first start)